# Есть ли функция для форматирования строки?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Современные языки программирования позволяют разработчику создавать строки с метками-заполнителями и заменять правильные значения функцией/методом, обычно называемым `format`.

Это может выглядеть так:

```
"Hi {0}! How are you?".format('John');
```

Есть ли какая-нибудь функция в SQL или PL/SQL с таким же поведением? Или какая тут лучшая практика?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [String formatting in Oracle (PL/)SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30964648) от участника [@tjati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321643/tjati)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30964648

Answer (score 6):

Воспользуйтеь пакетом [UTL_LMS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_LMS.html#GUID-9EBA2B74-FAC1-480D-B416-29F19A47F224), а именно функцией `format_message()`:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line (utl_lms.format_message ( -
    'Привет %s! Как дела %s? На все %d?', 'Вася', 'Вася', 100));
```

Результат:

> Привет Вася! Как дела Вася? На все 100?

Следует заметить:

1. Работает только в PL/SQL блокe, но не в SQL запросе.
2. Должны быть переданы значения для каждой метки-заполнителя: `%s` для строки, `%d` для чисел.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30965565) от участника [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nick-krasnov)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать пользовательский тип. Он более гибкий и его можно использовать в SQL:

```sql
select stringT (
    'Привет {1}! Дашь {2} руб., {1}? ').format (varargs ('Вася', 100)) formated
from dual
/

FORMATED
----------------------------------
Привет Вася! Дашь 100 руб., Вася?
```

Реализация пользовательского типа:

```sql
create or replace type varargs as table of varchar2 (32)
/
create or replace type stringT as object (
    s varchar2 (4000),
    member function format (args varargs) return varchar2)
/
create or replace type body stringT as 
    member function format (args varargs) return varchar2 is 
        pos int;
        ret varchar2 (4000) := self.s;
    begin 
        for i in 1..regexp_count (ret, '{(\d+)}') loop 
            pos := regexp_substr (ret, '{(\d+)}', 1, 1, null, 1);
            ret := regexp_replace (ret, '{(\d+)}', args(pos), 1, 1);
        end loop;
        return ret;
    end;
end;    
/
```