# Есть ли аналог RAISE NOTICE в Oracle?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, plsql

В PostgreSQL есть команда `RAISE NOTICE`, которая выводит сообщения.

Например, здесь выведется сообщение, и % будет заменён на значение `v_job_id`:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Вызов функции cs_create_job(%)', v_job_id;
```

Мне интересно, есть ли что-то похожее в Oracle.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть [PRINT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm#SQPUG051). Есть [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036). И вообще много чего есть...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболе близкий аналог [RAISE NOTICE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) в Oracle это:

- [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-C1400094-18D5-4F36-A2C9-D28B0E12FD8C) для вывода сообщения клиенту
- [UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_LMS.html#GUID-9EBA2B74-FAC1-480D-B416-29F19A47F224) для форматирования сообщения

[Воспроизводимый](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf1ae284f3f504691c693dc2b24617c4) пример:

```
set serveroutput on

declare 
    func_name varchar2 (32) := 'cs_create_job';
    job_id pls_integer := 42;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line (
        utl_lms.format_message ('Вызов функции %s(%d)', func_name, job_id));
end;
/
```

> Вызов функции cs_create_job(42)

Следует учесть, что:

- `DBMS_OUTPUT` записывает все сообшения во внутренний буфер и он никуда не выводится. Это задача клиентского приложения - получить сообщения из буфера и вывести их. Во многих инструментах для получения и вывода буфера есть переменная `serveroutput`.
- В отличае от `RAISE NOTICE`, в Oracle нет возможности записать сообщение в лог сервера.
- `UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE` имеет некоторые ограничения на типы данных принимаемые в аргументах. Кто столнётся, тому поможет [этот топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1186366).